# How to replace value of column depending on another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this:

Table 1:

| Year | Futur |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | PO |
| 2021 | P1 |
| 2021 | P2 |
| 2022 | PO |
| 2022 | P1 |
| 2022 | P2 |

Table 2:

| Year2 | Futur2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2021 |
| 2021 | 2022 |
| 2021 | 2023 |
| 2022 | 2022 |
| 2022 | 2023 |
| 2022 | 2024 |

And my aim is to transform Table 1 to have this :

| Year2 | Futur2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2021 |
| 2021 | 2022 |
| 2021 | 2023 |
| 2022 | 2022 |
| 2022 | 2023 |
| 2022 | 2024 |

So I would like replace all `P0`, `P1`, `P2` with the right value from **Table 2**, for example for `2021`, `P0` is `2021`, but in `2022`, `P0` is `2022`, same for `P1`, `P2`, ...   I can't use a join because I would have too much value otherwise.

Thanks for reading me

Comment: Well, I edited your question but it's still hard to understand. If you want the first table to be the same as the second one, then just use the second table. If that doesn't answer your question, there might be things you forgot to tell.

Comment: Hm, I try to do the link between PO and 2021 or 2022, because P0 correspond to 2021 or 2022 and I would like to have the right correspondance